# expressjs router get :id multi level

Tags: node.js, express

My questions is quite complicated to explain so i will try best.

If have a router set up
Similar to this

```
app.get('/example/:id', function(req, res, next) { console.log(req.params.id); });
```

My question is, this example above will only capture the :id of the first level
Meaning  'example.com/example/test' would return 'test' in the terminal log.

How would i achieve 
example.com/example/test/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4
So i can have the desired output of an array from req.params.ids

```
{'test','sub1','sub2','sub3','sub4'}
```

I realise i could create a new router for each level i'm wanting capture.
but i feel like there could be a way to do it more simply.

Comment: You can always use params as you intend to but the better way can be if you use POST and send these values in the body. To use these as multiple in req.params you can see this

app.get('/example/:id/:sub1/:sub2', function(req, res, next) { console.log(req.params); });

This will give you an object with values of id, sub1 and sub2

Comment: Post would be ideal however i need this as a get request as its a frontend
So the url would be pointing to this examples above.

Comment: @UtkarshMehrotra also having app.get like your example would mean that if i was go drop a level the get command would not see this router.

I guess my question is if express a 'AND or OR' command when it comes to the routers

Answer (score 0):

see this example `:id` route, maybe help you

```
Route path: /example/:id/example1/:id1
Request URL: http://localhost:xxxx/example/1/example1/2
req.params: { "example": "1", "example1": "2" }

app.get('/example/:id/example1/:id1', function(req, res, next) { 
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

or see this example:

```
app.get('/fruit/:example1/:example2', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

and see this:

```
/api?paramA=valueA&paramB=valueB

router.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.paramA);     // valueA
    console.log(req.query.paramB);     // valueB
    console.log(req.query.paramC);     // undefined (doesn't exist)
});
```